# Regex to make sure that outside a certain tag there aren't any other tags

Tags: regex, tags

I'm trying to create a **regular expression** that makes sure that there are **no other tags outside a certain tag**.

The following should **fail**:

- `This <F>is</F> a test <ID><F>sentence</F></ID> for stackoverflow.`
- `This <ID><M>is</M></ID> a test <F>sentence</F> for stackoverflow.`

This one should **pass**:

- `This is a test <ID><F>sentence</F></ID> for stackoverflow.`
- `This is a test <ID><F>sentence</F></ID> for <ID>stackoverflow.</ID>`

This is what I have **tried** so far:

1. Match the **correct tag**: `(<ID>.+?<\/ID>)`
2. Make sure that there are **no tags before the matched tag**: `(?<![<>].+?)(<ID>.+?<\/ID>)`
3. Make sure that there are **no tags after the matched tag**: `(?<![<>].+?)(<ID>.+?<\/ID>)(?!.+?[<>])`

Part **3** is where the problem relies. When I add this part the match just expands to the last tag in order to satisfy the **negative lookahead** as you can see in the following screenshots:

- No negative lookahead:
  [image: No negative lookahead]
- Negative lookahead:
  [image: Negative lookahead]

Comment: Is this for PCRE, else what tool/lang?

Comment: [If `\K` is supported](https://so.parthpatel.net/regex/doc/1338/match-reset-k), try [`^[^><]*\K<ID>(?:(?!<ID).)+?<\/ID>(?=[^><]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/hQob8r/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble thanks for your help. Without the \K it also worked. I actually forgot something. Only tags that are not ID outside of the ID tags should fail.